# How to count when using resultmap?

Tags: mysql, mybatis

I'm tring to do a page query using Mybatis resultmap, I have to join Post since there is a condition in where clause, but how can I get the correct number of Blog since it is a one-to-many relation?

```
<select id="selectBlog" resultMap="blogResult">
  select
  B.id as blog_id,
  B.title as blog_title,
  B.author_id as blog_author_id,
  P.id as post_id,
  P.subject as post_subject,
  P.body as post_body
  from Blog B
  left join Post P on B.id = P.blog_id
  where B.id = #{id}
  and P.subject=#{postSubject}
</select>

<resultMap id="blogResult" type="Blog">
  <id property="id" column="blog_id" />
  <result property="title" column="blog_title"/>
  <collection property="posts" ofType="Post">
    <id property="id" column="post_id"/>
    <result property="subject" column="post_subject"/>
    <result property="body" column="post_body"/>
  </collection>
</resultMap>
```

---

**edit**
I'm sorry I was not clear. That seems easy and I find a solution:

```
<select id="count" resultType="java.lang.Integer">
  select
  count(distinct B.id)
  from Blog B
  left join Post P on B.id = P.blog_id
  where B.id = #{id}
  and P.subject=#{postSubject}
</select>
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. You probably know about `select count(*) from blog` so you need something else but you did not explain what exactly. What is the expected mapper method API? What data do you want to get from it?